# C# SQLite Datgridview to display database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite

I have a data grid view that is connected to a database.
So, the flow is

datagridview's source is a binding source.
the binding source is related to a dataset.
the dataset has a database adapter that is connected to a database say test.db

Every-time i open the program, it loads this database. But i am able to open other databases if they are of the same type (i.e Columns and Column datatype)

I want to know if this is the correct way of connecting a datagrid view to a database.
Also, 
Is it possible for me to modify the connection string of the adapter dynamically.?

Answer (score 0):

Your process seems fine.

You can set the `ConnectionString` property to whatever you want; you should use the `ConnectionStringBuilder` class to safely build the connection strings.